# syntax error: 'constant' for a windows sdk file

Tags: c++, urlmon

I'm getting this weird error when compiling a project:

[image: Error Output].

But urlmon.h is a windows sdk, why is it erroring? when I click it, it brings me here:

[image: urlmon.h]

which is very odd

Path of urlmon.h: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include`
Urlmon Code: https://pastebin.com/ardbRFBp

Comment: Please don't link to code and output. Stackoverflow questions should be self contained, so post everything relevant *in* the question as *text* (preferably in [mcve] form).

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by something in your own code somewhere before the inclusion of that file. Create a [mcve].

Comment: Right-click PARSE_ACTION and select "Go To Definition".  Ought to show you the macro that caused the error.

Comment: you mean PARSE_ARCHOR?

Comment: He surely meant `PARSE_ANCHOR`. (To address a comment author personally, please, prefix your comment with `@` and the name of that person. In this case, the author will get a notification. This and other hints you get when you take the [Tour].)

Answer (score 0):

A couple years old now, but I wanted to record what my conflict was when I ran into this exact error.

`PARSE_ANCHOR` was conflicting with `w3c-libwww/Library/src/HTParse.h`:
`#define PARSE_ANCHOR        PARSE_VIEW`

I didn't see anywhere that used that definition so I commented it out and it was fine here. No problems compiling after that.